# How to compare python lists of dicts for unordered sameness?

Tags: python

I have the following 8 (possibly non-unique) lists in python:

```
>>> a = [{9: {10:11}}, {}, {}]
>>> b = [{1:2}, {3:4}, {5:6}]
>>> c = [{}, {}, {}]
>>> d = [{1:2}, {3:4}, {5:6}]
>>> w = [{}, {}, {}]
>>> x = [{1:2}, {3:4}, {5:6}]
>>> y = [{}, {}, {}]
>>> z = [{1:2}, {3:4}, {5:6}]
```

I want to check if any combination of (a,b,c,d) is the same as any combination of (w,x,y,z). IE: if `{a, b, c, d} == {w, x, y, z}`. However, because of the datatypes of these lists, I cannot easily put them into a set. They are unhashable.

What's the most pythonic way to do it?

I wanted to do the following but it didn't work:

```
>>> set([a,b,c,d]) == set([w,x,y,z])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So then I tried the following, but it didn't work either:

```
set([tuple(i) for i in [a,b,c,d]]) == set([tuple(i) for i in [w,x,y,z]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How can I write something pretty and efficient that will do the comparison that I need?

Comment: What is a combination of (a,b,c,d)? Please give an example.

Comment: Rory, Yes! I edited my question for clarification.

Comment: Could be `all([all([x == y for x, y in zip(firstGroup, lastGroup)]) for firstGroup, lastGroup in zip([a,b,c,d], [w,x,y,z])])`

Comment: isn't `{a, b, c, d} == {w, x, y, z}` ordered sameness?

Comment: @snapcrack In theory, but neither lists nor dicts are hashable.

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) by turning each list of dictionaries to a frozenset of frozensets, with the internal frozensets being each dictionary's items:

```
def freeze(li):
    return frozenset(frozenset(d.items()) for d in li)

a = freeze(a)
b = freeze(b)
c = freeze(c)
d = freeze(d)
w = freeze(w)
x = freeze(x)
y = freeze(y)
z = freeze(z)

print(z)
# frozenset({frozenset({(3, 4)}), frozenset({(5, 6)}), frozenset({(1, 2)})})

print({a, b, c, d} == {w, x, y, z})
# True
```

Comment: Now what if the dictionaries in the list contain sub-dictionaries?
This breaks down in that case because `freeze()` throws an exception. I just edited the question to include this wrinkle.

Comment: @SaqibAli then you'd have to come up with a recursive version of `freeze`

Answer (score 0):

@DeepSpace's answer works only if each sub-dict in a list is unique, since `[a, b, c, d]` should not be considered the same as `[a, a, b, c, d]`, but with @DeepSpace's use of the `set` constructor, they will be treated as the same.

To correctly account for possible duplicating items in the list, you can use `collections.Counter` instead:

```
from collections import Counter
def freeze(li):
    return frozenset(frozenset(d.items()) for d in li)
print(Counter(map(freeze, [a, b, c, d])) == Counter(map(freeze, [a, a, b, c, d])))
```

Also, in case the sub-dicts contain lists or dicts as values, you can make it a recursive function instead:

```
def freeze(o):
    if isinstance(o, list):
        return frozenset(Counter(map(freeze, o)).items())
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        return frozenset((k, freeze(v)) for k, v in o.items())
    return o
print(freeze([a,b,c,d]) == freeze([x,w,y,z]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate hashable objects such as:

```py
def fset(item):
    l = []
    for k, v in item.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            l.append((k, fset(v)))
        else:
            l.append((k, v))

    return frozenset(l)

a = [{9: {10:11}}, {}, {}]
fa = [fset(i) for i in a]

>>> fa
[frozenset({(9, frozenset({(10, 11)}))}), frozenset(), frozenset()]
```

Applying the same to all lists , you'll have lists of frozensets that you can check sameness of combinations by simply using == operator.

For example:

```py
fa = [fset(i) for i in a]
fb = [fset(i) for i in b]
...

from itertools import combinations

for c1, c2 in combinations([fa, fb, fc, fd],2):
    for c3, c4 in combinations([fw, fx, fy, fz], 2):
       print(frozenset(c1 + c2) == frozenset(c3 + c4))
```